# Angular erro ao retornar string de função no service: Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Estou tendo o seguinte problema ao tentar retornar uma `string` de uma variável do `service` para qualquer outra função, o que é estranho pois todas as variáveis são strings como o retorno das funções.

**teste.service.ts**

```
private oneString:string = "hi";

getOneString(): string {
    return this.oneString.
}
```

**myFunction.ts**

```
constructor(private testeService: TesteService) { } 

private myString:string = this.service.getOneString; 

console.log(myString);
```

> Erro: Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'string'

Comment: Você reparou que no seu constructor você declarou `testeService` e em myString chamou `service`?

Comment: Opa, erro de digitação, mas obrigada.

Comment: Deixe a pergunta sem a correção pois assim a próxima pessoa que pesquisar por esse erro também poderá ser ajudada.

Comment: beleza, ja retornei para os service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema era que eu estava chamando `this.testeService.getOneString`, sendo que deveria ser chamado era: `this.testeService.getOneString()`
Também conforme comentado o outro problema era o this.service, que deveria ser this.testeService.

Resolvido !

Answer (score 3):

No construtor você chama o seu serviço `TesteService` com o seguinte nome `testeService`, porem ao chama o serviço você coloca no código `this.service`, ou seja, para funcionar você deve colocar `this.testeService`, como abaixo

**myFunction.ts**

```
constructor(private testeService: TesteService) { } 

private myString:string = this.testeService.getOneString(); 

console.log(myString);
```